# Python scope/namespace across modules

Tags: python, scope

I have a question related to scoping in python. Below is the code snippet:

file: settings.py

```
#module settings
fruit = 'banana'

def set_fruit(val):
    global fruit
    print 'Setting fruit ', fruit, ' to ', val
    fruit = val
```

file: helper.py

```
#module helper
from settings import fruit

class Helper(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'Inside Helper fruit = ', fruit
```

file: controller.py

```
#module controller
import settings
import helper

class Controller(object):
    def __init__(self):
        settings.set_fruit('apple')
        print 'Controller: settings.fruit = ', settings.fruit

Controller()
print 'fruit = ', settings.fruit
helper.Helper()
```

`settings.py` has global settings that are used by various modules. Some of these settings needs to be changed during start up by controller. I want to know why the settings changed by controller is not visible to others, in this case to helper module.

Here is the output that I get:

```
$ python controller.py
Setting fruit  banana  to  apple
Controller: settings.fruit =  apple
fruit =  apple
Inside Helper fruit =  banana
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moment you do `from settings import fruit` you created a new `fruit` name in your `helper` module that is *separate* from the `settings.fruit` name. It merely references the same object.

Your `settings.set_fruit()` method then rebinds the `settings.fruit` to point it to a new object, but the `helper.fruit` reference cannot follow suit; it is separate after all.

All this is no different from creating two separate local variables that reference a value:

```
fruit = 'banana'
another_fruit = fruit
fruit = 'apple'
print another_fruit
```

The work-around is to do what you did in the `controller` module; only reference names within `settings` as attributes on the module. That way you'll always use just the one reference, it is the reference to the `settings` module that is shared across your other modules then.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. That explains it.